# Existem ferramentas de BI / OLAP para a plataforma MEAN.JS?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express.js, business-intelligence

Alguém pode me indicar um framework de BI / OLAP ou ao menos um Chart Engine, preferencialmente open-source, que se integre adequadamente a plataforma [MEAN.JS](http://meanjs.org/) ou [MEAN.IO](http://mean.io/) com arquitetura *SPA - Single Page Application*?

Eu conheço o **keen.io**. Ele é gratuito em baixo volume transacional, mas não é open-source.

O **Pentaho** é uma ótima ferramenta de BI, open-source, possui RESTful Services e suporta *MongoDB*, mas seu dashboard ainda preconiza o Java no lado servidor e está uma geração atrás de frameworks como *Angular.JS* e *Node.JS*, pois só estão migrando agora para *jQuery* e *Bootstrap*.

Agradeço por qualquer contribuição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Descoberta 1

Existe uma API incrível, similar a *jQuery* em objetivo de manipular o *DOM* para você para compôr gráficos chart, chamada **D3.JS - Data-Driven Documents - d3js.org**

### Descoberta 2

Existe um mecanismo de charts chamado **NVD3 - nvd3.org**, construído sobre *D3.JS*, que permite que você empregue componentes chart reusáveis em suas aplicações *Javascript*.

### Descoberta 3

Existe um módulo *Angular.JS* chamado **AngularJS-NVD3-directives** http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/, que integra os componentes chart do *NVD3* dentro de diretivas do *Angular.JS*, permitindo usá-los nativamente em suas aplicações *Angular.JS*.

### A Solução Open Source para MEAN Stack

Você pode integrar componentes *AngularJS-NVD3-directives* com o Pentaho RESTful services via *Mongoose* acessando seus dados *MongoDB* para construir paineis de controle (dashboards e scoreboards) para suas aplicações.

Você ainda precisará escrever código para integrar cada um dos componentes de um painel de controle como grid layout, temas, projeção e visibilidade de campos, filtro, ordenação, tabelas dinâmicas (pivot) e gráficos chart.

Hoje, o processo de desenvolvimento de paineis de controle não é simples e direto, mas você já possui uma solução open source boa o suficiente para conceber aplicações impressionantes.

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma opção open-source, que é o Cubes, no qual usa a ferramenta Slicer
http://cubes.databrewery.org/

Ele é feito em Python e possui uma biblioteca cliente em Javascript: https://github.com/Stiivi/cubes.js/

Você pode configurar e usar esta ferramenta como um servidor OLAP e rodar as queries através do javascript diretamente no browser e pegar o resultado como JSON.

Referências:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25133209/olap-server-for-nodejs